# How to save the output in a row of a matrix, each time a loop runs?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix, save

I am running a loop, but I want to store the output each time it runs, in a row of a matrix, so if I run it let's say 3 times, I need a 3xncol matrix!
I tried to do it with the following code but it says:
"number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

```
X1=1
X2=2
X3=3

results1= matrix(NA, nrow= 7, ncol=3, byrow=FALSE)
colnames(results1)<- c("High", "Medium", "Low")

for (i in 1:7){

X1<-4+X1
X2<-2*X1
X3<-3*X2

  results1[i,]<-c(X1,X2,X3)
}
```

I'm a newbie to R, but the point is I want to make sure if the computer crashes, I have saved up to whatever the loop was able to run.

P.S: Example edited after Akrun commented a good point!

Comment: The number of columns is 3 while you concatenate X1, X2, X3 to a length of 9

Comment: @akrun I don't follow, so you are saying I should store them in a 1*3 matrix and then attach them together? How exactly? (If that is what you mean)

Comment: You can check the output of  `c(X1,X2,X3)#
[1] 1 1 2 2 1 3 1 1 1` and the number of columns in results1 is just 3 for each row

Comment: @akrun right! Sorry! the example will be edited, in reality, X1, X2, X3 will be single numbers inside the loop, not a vector.

Comment: Can you check whether you need the solution posted below

Comment: With your edit, what is hte issue.  I guess you will get the same value for each row

Comment: @Akrun I edited the example as you mentioned, and the following answer wouldn't be the situation I am dealing with, however, I believe it will help others if they face a similar problem! I will save it somewhere for me!

Comment: Your new edit will only replicate the same value for each row.  Is that what you wanted

Comment: you may check my solution post where it is showed how to deal with vectors

Comment: @akrun loop doesn't run, says "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

Comment: If the number of rows of 'results1' is the same as the length of X1, X2, X3, it should work

Comment: The real situation I am dealing with, is a 600 line code and I have around 37 columns with 300 rows, each column is a single value, not a vector, and when I get at then end of the loop where I want to save them in the matrix, that error happens

Comment: Sorry, your example may not be reflecting the exact situation you are facing

Comment: @akrun I edited it once again, assuming a 7 row, 3 col matrix

Comment: so you are recursively changing hte original object.  Now, your code is working fine for me though

Comment: In your original dataset, if you have 37 columns, and in each row you are updating with three values i.e. `c(X1,X2,X3)` there is  a length difference i.e. 37 - 3

Comment: @akrun the values don't really matter, it is just an example, what is driving me crazy is why it can not save each rows=the results when the loop runs for the first time, ..., when the loop runs for the 7th time in a matrix! (In reality, it is a simulation study and each time the lopp runs, it uses a different data set, so the values will be different)

Comment: I hope you underestand the issue i.e. `length(c(X1, X2, X3))` should be equal to number of columns of the data

Comment: ok, maybe your examples are not reflecting the actual case.   As I said earlier, if the number of columns are the same as the length of concatenated vectors, it should work

Comment: @akrun I totally get what you mean, and yes, I have 37 values and that is why I chose 37 as the number of columns, in the example I provided here, I have 3 values so 3 columns too

Comment: Your code does not give any error/warning to me.